# Prove: Use the triangle inequality to prove that for all $x, y, | |x| − |y| | ≤ |x − y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

Prove: Use the triangle inequality to prove that for all $x, y, | |x| − |y| | ≤ |x − y|$

> Proof:
>
> If $x ≥ 0$ and $y ≥ 0$, then both sides of the
>   inequality are the same.
>
> Also if $x ≤ 0$ and $y ≤ 0$ then both sides of the
>   inequality are the same.
>
> Assume $x ≥ 0$ and $y ≤ 0$ then $|x| = x$, and $|y| = −y$, and so:
>
> $||x|| = ||x − y + y|| ≤ ||x − y + y|| ⇒ ||x−y||≤||x − y||$
>
> and
>
> $||y|| = ||x − y − x|| ≤ ||x − y|| + ||x|| ⇒ −(||x||−||y||) ≤ ||x − y||$

How do I approach this? Is this a good start?

### Update:

I feel the following approach is a little bit more clear.

> Proof:
>
> Case $x≥0$ and $y≥0$: We have both sides equal each-other
>
> Case $x≤0$ and $y≤0$: We also have both sides equal each-other
>
> Case $x≥0$ and $y≤0$: Then $|x|=x$, and $|y|=−y$, and so
>   $||x|| = ||x − y + y|| ≤ ||x − y + y|| ⇒ ||x−y||≤||x − y||$
>
> Case $x≤0$ and $y≥0$: Then $|x|=-x$, and $|y|=y$, and so
>   $||y|| = ||x − y − x|| ≤ ||x − y|| + ||x|| ⇒ −(||x||−||y||) ≤ ||x − y||$
>
> QED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  What does the triangle inequality tell you about $|z+y|$?  And then what do you get if you substitute $z=x-y$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Start with 
$$
|x|=|x-y+y|
$$

and use triangle inequality.